# React.ComponentPropsWithRef vs React.forwardRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to understand why we need to use React.forwardRef.

I can define props as React.ComponentPropsWithRef<'input'> and pass a ref to the component.

Please help me understand what is wrong with doing this.

Thank you.

```
type TextboxProps = React.ComponentPropsWithRef<'input'>;

const Textbox = (props: TextboxProps): ReactElement | null => {
    return (
        <input
            type='number'
            value={props.value}
            onChange={props.onChange}
            ref={props.ref}
        />

    );
};

export { Textbox };
```

Comment: For one, there's the part where `ComponentPropsWithRef` isn't mentioned anywhere in [the official react documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.ComponentPropsWithRef` only sets the type of the props of the component for the `ref` property to exist (as well as the other native attributes of the underlying element). However, without using `React.forwardRef`, passing the `ref` prop has no effect. `ref.current` will always be whatever initial value was passed to `useRef`.